# How to rotate particles around the curve/path of their travel with geometry nodes

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

This is the node setup to morph particles between two meshes by traveling curved path. I want them to rotate around the path while traveling so flow look like turbulent.

I am very beginner at geometry nodes, so specifically at which place, what nodes should I put to achieve that ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Tilt* value of the curve points in this case.

This value is available in Edit-Mode:

[image]

When you trim the curve in your geometry nodes, you get the position and rotation of the respective point on the curve, which you then transfer to the instantiated objects.

Like this:

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

OK, I have tried to integrate this better in your example. Maybe this version will help you.
However, I don't know exactly what your final result should look like, so I restructured it and implemented it in a simple way to give you a clue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for responding, actually i didn't knew how to include blender files in question, now i have uploaded two files. 1. Original file which contains nodes as shown in screenshot uploaded by me (two-mesh-morph_original.blend) and 2. my trial file made according to your instructions to rotate particles (two-mesh-morph_trial.blend). i tried to include nodes as per your instruction but i am getting particles location offset to curve and getting very less rotation. this is definitely my mistake doing it. requesting to review my fault. thank you very much again

Comment: This is it, that's exactly what I want. thank you so much for giving your precious time. what I actually want is an intro with this effect: particles travels and gathers in the form of some alphabet letters. there are very few tutorials for geometry nodes with particles available on internet, so you did great job for me as well as other blender users who are willing to learn particles with geometry nodes

Comment: I tried to imitate/copy whole node tree you just provided above but I am getting different result (two mesh objects came together and not morphing properly).
This is the last time i am torturing you. please point out my fault in this file (take a look when you're totally free)
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AzZx0M6G" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AzZx0M6G/)

Comment: [Also]: i am getting this error message every time i open that file after re-opening it: "1 libraries and 82 linked data-blocks are missing (including 0 ObjectData and 0 Proxies), please check the Info and Outliner editors for details"

Comment: Regarding your problem, there are two things: 1. You need to disable "Local space" in the node "Rotate Instances"; 2. Don't scale the curve in "Object Mode", just scale it in "Edit Mode" instead.

Comment: Regarding the error message: Click on "File -> Clean up -> Recursive Unused Data-Blocks", save it, open it again.  ...it looks like some ballast has crept into your file.

Comment: Task completed beautifully. thank you so much for guiding a beginner. it's an honour for me to talk with you directly. i am not saying much but you're too intelligent as well as great person that you spend time for noob person like me. i am a 3d modeling artist (3ds max) btw and don't hesitate to ask me for any labour work if you want to get it done. Thank you very much again